# How can I test Firebase Remote Configs' country selector on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I've set up an Android project with different Remote Config Values for the UK and the USA. On IOS, it's easy to change the country that Firebase recognises by changing General > Language & Region > Region.

I haven't been able to do the same on Android. I've tried changing the language settings, the SimCountryIso, and the SimCountryIso. Nothing has worked so far.

Thanks for the help!